# masked array from image

Tags: python, arrays, mask

I have an image that I need to mask, based on another image. That is, the mask is to be read from a monochrome image file (not a small array with a simple shape) and applied to another image. I need to compute the median of the masked image within a radius of 25 pixels. I've been playing around with the suggestions from http://prancer.physics.louisville.edu/astrowiki/index.php/Image_processing_with_Python_and_SciPy#Masked_image_operations
but I can't see how to apply the mask to the image a 25-pixel-radius patch at a time. Each of the image files are 901 x 877 pixels.

I thought about piling the values from the mask onto another dimension of the image array and using an if...then loop to look at the pixels in the array at the same time as the pixels in the image, but that seems like a really inefficient way to do it.
This is the code I'm using for the patch:

```
import numpy as np
def patch_filter(image_data, radius):
    kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1))
    y, x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
    mask = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
    kernel[mask] = 1                
    filtered_image = gf(image_data, np.median, footprint = kernel)
    return filtered_image
```

and this works fine when the image is not masked.
Any ideas for applying the mask to the image?

EDIT: 
Here's what I've come up with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from scipy.ndimage.filters import generic_filter as gf

#   Read images into arrays
hdulist = fits.open('xbulge-w1.fits')
w1data = hdulist[0].data               # This is the image

hdulistmask = fits.open('xbulge-mask.fits')
maskdata = hdulistmask[0].data         # This is the mask

#   Define physical shape of filter
def patch_filter(image_data, radius):
    kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1))
    y, x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
    patch = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
    kernel[patch] = 1                
    filtered_image = gf(image_data, np.median, footprint = kernel)
    return filtered_image

mx1 = np.ma.masked_array(w1data, mask=maskdata)

radius = 25

w1masked_filtered = patch_filter(mx1, radius)
```

I'd then either plt.show() or plt.savefig().
Does that look like it would work?

Comment: Here's what I've come up with: